# How to convert hg19.bit file to hg19.fa file using twobitreader package?

Tags: python-2.7

I have downloaded hg19.2bit file and I am keeping it in D drive. I have imported twobitreader package inside python software on windows. Now any one help me how to use the package in python code so that it converts hg19.2bit to hg19.fa file.

The sample code I tried is

```
import twobitreader
def get_a(n):
    genome = twobitreader.TwoBitFile('hg19.2bit')
    bedfile = open(n+'.bed', 'r')
    o_f = open(n+'_FASTA.fa', 'w')
    twobitreader.twobit_reader(genome, bedfile,o_f.write)
    bedfile.close()
    o_f.close()
```

I have taken the above file from net. I have saved the above file in the name sample.py. when i am executing the program nothing is getting printed and no fasta file has been generated.
can anyone help me with full code or how to write the code for conversion.

Comment: Are you actually calling the `get_a(n)` function?

Comment: yes I have used def get_a(n): in my program

Comment: What do you mean by "using def get_an(n)"? That sounds like you only defined; if you call it, you would say "using get_an('name')". Have you tried debugging the function by adding `print` statements?

Comment: Here is the modified code i have used after your suggestion import twobitreader
def get_a(n):
    "using get_a('n')"
    genome = twobitreader.TwoBitFile('hg19.2bit')
    bedfile = open(n+'.bed', 'r')
    o_f = open(n+'_FASTA.fa', 'w')
    print bedfile
    twobitreader.twobit_reader(genome, bedfile,o_f.write)
    bedfile.close()
    o_f.close(). But still I am not getting any thing printed. Can you please  help me about full code in python to convert hg19.bit file to fasta file.

Comment: Please update the code in your question, not in a comment (which has little formatting). And show that you also *call* the function.

Comment: I  have tried using call function. but it is asking for BED file. Then how to create a BED file for hg19.2bit using python?

Comment: I assumed you this ".bed" file. So if you're asking how to create this file, that's a different question, and it sounds like you may first want to read up more about what you actually want and need to do.